# What is the 'PipelinesSDK' user and why has it been added to all of my code Repos?

Tags: azure-devops

We recently realized that a user 'PipelinesSDK' has elevated permissions (check in, contribute, label, manage branch, etc.) to all of our Repos.  It appears to be an Microsoft OOTB account, and is a member of the 'Security Service Group'  Other accounts that are members of the 'Security Service Group' include:  Agent Pool Service (n), Hosted - Agent Service, Hosted VS2017 - Agent Service  Agent Service, etc.

I cannot find a reference to this account (PipelinesSDK) on the Microsoft forums.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but for future reference here are the [docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#service-accounts)

**PipelineSDK:**
Added as needed to support the Pipelines policy service scope tokens. This user account is similar to the build service identities but supports locking down permissions separately. In practice, the tokens that involve this identity are granted read-only permissions to pipeline resources and the one-time ability to approve policy requests. This account should be treated in the same way that the build service identities are treated.